# My input of type date always returns null to the object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

So I have this view which should return a name and two dates, but the dates seem to always be null.

I binded an alert to the create button to see what date js would read from the input field and it was always the right one, but when going back to the post action, the object always has null value on StartedOn and FinishedOn (if they are date? if not it gives me 01/01/2001 as date and when i try to save it in database it throws exception "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value").

My question is, why does it always return null if nullable or 01/01/2001 if not and how can I fix it?

**My view:**

```
@model Data.Project

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Project</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control",type="date" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinishedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FinishedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" , type = "date" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="11" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#11").on("click",function() {
                alert($("#StartedOn").val());
            })
        })
    </script>
}
```

**My action:**(here the dates are allredy null)

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                UtilityContext.AddProject(project);
                UtilityContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }
```

**My model:**

```
 public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? StartedOn { get; set; }

        public DateTime? FinishedOn { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> EmployeesOnIt { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the object always has null value on StartedOn and FinishedOn

Because you told it *not* to bind those values:

```
[Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Project project
```

Maybe you should bind them:

```
[Bind(Include = "Id,Name,StartedOn,FinishedOn")] Project project
```

Comment: I've done the same exact thing multiple times.  It happens.